# Drupal: Edit !name variable in my Drupal to first name?

Tags: drupal, variables, drupal-6

I’ve a bit of annoying problem with a Drupal site. I’ve a “recommend to a friend” field where one can send an article link to an E-mail address. The problem is, that it uses the variable **!name** in the mail and when I’m receive a mail, it uses the name before the “@” in my mail.

I use my mail as username, so if I’ve registered a user with the username: johndoe@google.com it will present the **!name** variable as **johndoe**.

What I want is to display the first name (and maybe the last name) so it says: John Doe recommends this article …

But how can I do that? I’ve search like crazy for the setting.

Thanks
Sincere
- Mestika

Comment: Do you have the realname module installed?  We've used that to get user's real names for input variables.

Comment: Hey, yeah it is installed but what do I do to get the real name??

Comment: $user->realname gets you the realname

Comment: This is probably just a question of theming or adding an own preprocessing function so that you can alter the variable values used for generating the name.

Answer (score 1):

To replace user names in quotes by reals names it's necessary to replace Phorum´s standard function for quoting. Since it only makes sense to have one module modifying the quoted text, you can disable this one part of this module. Use System Sanity Checks to control if there is only one module using the quote hook. The default value is "disabled". 
TUV Rheinland of North America

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the Custom Tokens module. I use it to get text from my user's Content Profile.